# string concatenation not working in select options field

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following php code embedded in a form (the purpose is basically to show and post something like this "city (country)" ):

```
 <select name="city">
        <option selected value=""></option>
        <?php
        foreach ($result_array as $rowarray){

            echo '<option value='.$rowarray[1].' ('.$rowarray[0].'>'.$rowarray[1].' ('.$rowarray[0].')</option>';
        }
        ?>
```

The funny thing is, when I post this form, this is what is sent to the $_POST variable:

```
array (size=7)
'city' => string 'Abu' (length=3)
```

For some reason, everything after the blank space in the city name does not get concatenated.
Now here's the thing, when I code it like this:

```
 echo '<option>'.$rowarray[1].' ('.$rowarray[0].')</option>';
```

Then this is what end up in the $_POST:

```
array (size=7)
'city' => string 'Abu Simbel (Egypt)' (length=18)
```

So bascially the exact same code for concatenating does not work when I put it in the "value" attribute of the option element.
What am I missing here?

Addition: The same thing happens when I concatenate like this:

```
'<option value='.$rowarray[1].'!'.$rowarray[0].'>'
```

so it is not due to the space in front of the brackets.

Comment: If your `value` contains spaces, then you need to quote it, strictly speaking, HTML element attributes should always be quoted anyway.... [HTML 101](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select)

Comment: And why do you have brackets inside tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to enclose your values in a `"` (and close a bracket):

```
echo '<option value="'.$rowarray[1].' ('.$rowarray[0].')">'.$rowarray[1].' ('.$rowarray[0].')</option>';
                    ^right here                        ^ and here
```